# $cordovaCaptureVideo duration does not work

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using `$cordovaCapture` to record video. The docs say the duration option will set the duration on to which the user can record video. But for some reason it does nothing for me. I have it set for 10 but I can record for however long I want. I want the video to stop recording at exactly 10 seconds.

```js
var options = {
    limit: 1,
    duration: 10,
    quality: 1
   };

$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
      // Success! Video data is here
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What S.O is working? The documentation says the limitations of that parameter, Android in particular is not allowed

[Document](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)

Comment: I am doing android. I saw that but since I was doing video, I thought it didn't matter. So I guess they should edit that document saying duration doesn't work for audio nor video. Thanks